# Is there any cXML server which exist in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, https, cxml

I need to integrate cXML data in an ERP, saddly this ERP doesn't support CXML, so i was thinking to use a cXML/HTTPs Server to get the cXML data then parse it.

I'm looking for an HTTPS server in c#/.net in order to receive these cXML stream.

I never dealed with cXML, it appear to be just an "xml".

Any people already deal with cXML ? A simple https server will be enough to get the cXML stream or i'm on the wrong way ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: See following : http://xml.cxml.org/current/cXMLReferenceGuide.pdf?force_isolation=true  CXML is a transfer protocol to send XML using HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Yeah, so, a simple https server in c# could do the job ? I have to see if it exist an https server in c# available.

Comment: CMXL is a protocol.  So it depends on the other end of the connection if a simple HTTP request would work.  That is why I provided the link.  I'm not familiar with the CXML protocol.  It looks simple, but not 100% sure.

Comment: cXML is a specific xml document format specified by cxml.org, the docuemnt format is used used by SAP Ariba, Coupa and Dynamiics 365, any transport method / protocol can used, SAP Ariba and Coupa uses APIs over HTTPS